# What's the difference between these two comments in Low Quality Posts queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

While reviewing [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts), one can choose to <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd>.
In this case, the following dialog is shown:

[image]

I can't see any difference between the 3rd and 4th comment:

> **This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment**
>
> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

> **This is a different question posted as an answer**
>
> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

They are very similar. They both say to ask a new question.
I usually use the first, because it's longer. I really don't know *when* to use one instead of another.

The [network FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029) is unclear, site-unspecific and omits comments.
When should I use one instead of another?

Comment: Why does the similarity between the two _comments_ matter? It's two different cases: one is "me too!", the other is a new question posted as an answer.

Comment: They seem pretty different to me. "I'm having this problem too"  and "How do i do X based on some criteria Y in another answer?" each clearly fall under one or the other. My guess would be "How do i do X based on some criteria Y in another answer?" is more common due to people having followup questions that should be asked as separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different cases and should be pretty easy to spot. Both types of answers should be recommended for deletion.

> **This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment**
>
> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

This comment is used when people post an answer stating they are having the same problem or asking if they ever found the answer. The comment states that this isn't an answer and if they have a different question they should ask it. It is also pointing out that they can possibly get more attention to the question by placing a bounty.

> **This is a different question posted as an answer**
>
> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Is used on answers where the author posted a question as an answer. This comment is used to point them in the direction of asking a question. It is also stating to link to the current question if there is relevant information on this. I would have to guess that that part was included as people are treading the Q&A as a discussion board so they are continuing on the original question.